# How to get stable foot contacts when a biped robot is standing still?

Tags: contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm simulating a biped robot in gazebo 1.7 but the foot contacts showed by the simulator are intermittent also when the robot is standing still.

DRCSim Atlas simulation shows constant and stable contacts on the feet when the robot is walking. How that is achieved?

Is it because the Atlas joint controllers, link contacts and solver parameters are better tuned than mine or there is something I'm missing?

There are some additional parameters to tune to get a better interaction with the ground?

I'm using the same contact model as the Atlas model for the foot body:

```
<gazebo reference="r_foot">
  <kp>6000000.0</kp>
  <kd>1.0</kd>
  <mu1>0.9</mu1>
  <mu2>0.9</mu2>
  <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
  <maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
  <minDepth>0.003</minDepth>
</gazebo>
```

If I simulate only Atlas foot, without controllers because there are no joints to control, the intermittent behavior appears. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Pictures of the Atlas robot with stable contacts: [atlas-contacts](http://db.tt/UlZJgehb)

Only one foot with intermittent contacts: [foot-contacts1](http://db.tt/OHexieaF) [foot-contact2](http://db.tt/DJ5dPaFO)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2765/how-to-get-stable-foot-contacts-when-a-biped-robot-is-standing-still?/) by [luca](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/187/luca/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Basically there is not enough damping in your system. Without damping energy is conserved and so propagates through the system like a perpetual motion machine, and the thing is constantly vibrating off the ground.

The atlas actually has had the same problem and they've recently started to fix it with higher damping values, and softer foot contacts. The contact model you list for the atlas foot is not the latest.

See the following for details:

- https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/680/feet-drift-when-standing-due-commit
- https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/269/update-foot-contact-with-more-realistic/diff#comment-241720

---

Originally posted by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) with karma: 283 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luca](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/187/luca/) on 2013-05-13**:
Thanks! I managed to get good results changing contact model parameters.